# Incomplete Pattern Match on Parameters

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

why does the following code give me a incomplete pattern match warning and a runtime exception.

```
 type Left =
     | L1 of int
     | L2 of int

 type Right =
     | R1 of int
     | R2 of int

 type Directions =
     | LeftDir of Left
     | RightDir of Right


 let unpack (LeftDir (L1 i)) = i

 let x = unpack (LeftDir (L1 10))
 let y = unpack (LeftDir (L2 20))
```

Obviously the answer is because IT IS a incomplete pattern match ;-)

But why is F# not smart enough (or the writers of the F# language spec for that matter) to know that `unpack` expects only a `LeftDir containing a L1`? Why is a complete pattern match necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conceptually, `LeftDir` and `L1` are not types (despite their being implemented that way on the IL-level); rather, *`Directions`* is a type and `LeftDir` is only one constructor for that type, and likewise for `Left` and `L1`. If this doesn't immediately make sense, revisit the concept of algebraic sum types.

As F# function parameters are strictly type-based (unlike some other languages), `unpack` necessarily takes an object of type `Directions`, and whether that object instance was constructed via `LeftDir` or `RightDir` must be determined at runtime; and if via `LeftDir`, likewise for whether its contained instance of `Left` was constructed via `L1` or `L2`.

A complete pattern match is *not* strictly necessary, but given that a core goal of strongly, statically-typed languages such as F# is to catch as many errors at compile-time as possible, a warning is given *recommending* a complete pattern match in order to avoid runtime errors.

Answer (score 2):

You explicitly define a function in a way that only handles one of the two possible cases, then you are surprised when you get an exception for the second case you didn't handle.

What do you think should happen otherwise?

The whole point of discriminated unions is to have a closed type with a known number of "subtypes" that you can handle in an exhaustive way.

You can very well write a function that cares only about a very specific case, like `LeftDir (L1 x)`, but the function still needs to be able to handle the other cases. You either provide that handling yourself, or you get it *for free* in the form of incomplete match exception.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is no way to specify at compile time that `unpack` takes a specific instance of `Directions`.  The only possibility is a run time check, so you get a compiler warning.