# What is the canonical way to transform a list of a specific member of a discriminated unions

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, discriminated-union

I have a list of a specific member of a DU that I want to transform after I have filtered another list for exactly this member.

```
type FooBar = 
     | Foo of int
     | Bar of int

type FooBarWrapper = FooWrapper of FooBar

let fbs = [Foo(1); Bar(2); Foo(3); Bar(4)]

let onlyFoos x = 
    match x with
        | Foo x -> true
        | _ -> false

let foos = fbs |> List.filter onlyFoos

let fooValues (Foo x) = x + 1

let result = foos |> List.map fooValues;;
```

Now this gives me an incomplete pattern match for

```
let fooValues (Foo x) = x + 1
               ^^^^^
```

As I dont match for Bars - but then - At that specific point in time I know that the list contains only Foos.

The only way is to rewrite `fooValues` like this

```
let fooValues x = 
    match x with
        | Foo x -> x + 1
        | _ -> failwith "Aint No Foo!"
```

Argh! Now I have to pattern match once again even though I absolutely know that there wont be any Bars here.

So what is the best/syntactically most pleasing way to implement this in F#?

And as a side note: does Haskell have the same issue?

Comment: You seem to be trying to ask the same question in a slightly different way - this reads almost as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910814/incomplete-pattern-match-on-parameters .  I think the solutions there apply here as well

Comment: most certainly :-) - still pretty new to F# and trying to find my way around it. And as always - there are cool features and there are "quirks" you have to live with if you want to harvest other features

Comment: One thing that F# taught me is: function overloading and currying are hard to combine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's an issue, it's rather the way DU are by design and yes, the same applies for Haskell. Otherwise you can use objects and subtypes.

But specifically for the sample code you provided, what about changing a bit the design?

```
let onlyFoos x = 
    match x with
        | Foo x -> Some x
        | _ -> None

let foos = fbs |> List.choose onlyFoos

let fooValues x = x + 1
let result = foos |> List.map (Foo << fooValues)
```

The idea is instead of storing the DU Tag with the data, just store the data alone. Otherwise the Tag will be redundant since you know that all elements will have the same Tag. Later on, when you mix them again you can re-tag them easily.